# Jenkins job to Delete TeamCity's work directory

Tags: powershell, jenkins, teamcity

I am writing PowerShell scripts to delete TeamCity work directory on daily basis, the script is working well in ideal condition(when none of the folder in work directory is in use). But when any build is executing in TeamCity and during that time if I execute the script, it shows failure.

```
#Cleanup work directory of TeamCity's build agent
$Path = "C:\BuildAgent\work"
$exclude = @("*.old", "*directory.map")
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Can anyone suggest how can I skip this particular condition without showing any failure so that all the files are deleted except the one which is in use.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [undocumented API call](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206217439-Scheduled-clean-sources) that allows you to clean sources on a particular agent.

Loop through all agents and make a POST request to:

```
http://teamcity/ajax.html?resetSources=<agentID>
```

Assuming you are using a new version of TeamCity, you will need to be aware of [CSRF protection](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/CSRF+Protection).